# Localize YAML file's content

Tags: yaml

I have the following YAML file (math-formulas.yml) for a product:

```
Name: Math formulas
Type: Book
Description: A book with math formulas
Price: 40 USD
```

The Name and Description needs to be localized into two languages: EN and FR.

What is the proper way to localize YAML file's content?

Should I have 3 files? One file?

I will use YAML files to insert data into my application database.

**UPDATE**

What do you think about this approach ([Yaml Parser Example](https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=TmFtZTogTWF0aCBmb3JtdWxhcwpUeXBlOiBCb29rCkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uOiAKICAtIEVOOiBBIGJvb2sgd2l0aCBtYXRoIGZvcm11bGFzCiAgLSBGUjogVW4gbGl2cmUgYXZlYyBkZXMgZm9ybXVsZXMgbWF0aMOpbWF0aXF1ZXMKUHJpY2U6IDQwIFVTRA==)):

```
Name: Math formulas
Type: Book
Description: 
  - EN: A book with math formulas
  - FR: Un livre avec des formules mathématiques
Price: 40 USD
```

Does this makes sense?

Comment: What makes you think there is a *proper* way? I can think of several possible ways.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a standard way. That is why I am asking ... What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ways I can think of: (Note: I used Google translate for example text.)

1. branch at the lowest level. I use local tags for identifying the language.

```
Name: [!en Math formulas, !fr formules mathématiques]
Type: Book
Description: [!en A book with math formulas,
              !fr Un livre avec des formules mathématiques]
Price: 40 USD
```

2. Use one language as default, with replacement text for the other one (this is what e.g. gettext does and guarantees you a fallback). I use `!t` for values that are translatable and `!translations` for the document that contains the replacements. Depending on your data model, you may not need either.

```
---
Name: !t Math formulas
Type: Book
Description: !t A book with math formulas
Price: 40 USD
--- !translations
fr:
  Math formulas: formules mathématiques
  A book with math formulas: Un livre avec des formules mathématiques
```

3. Assign IDs to translatable entities and define them elsewhere.

```
---
Name: !t 1
Type: Book
Description: !t 2
Price: 40 USD
--- !translations
en:
  1: Math formulas
  2: A book with math formulas
fr:
  1: formules mathématiques
  2: Un livre avec des formules
```

In both 2. and 3., you can also have one language file for each language instead of having all translations in one file. I would suggest solution 2 for readability (you can see the english text in the original document without it being cluttered with other translations right besides it, and in the additional translation document, you directly see the term you are translating. Also, it eliminates duplicate translations.

Comment: I just added another option on my question ... It seems a little bit more readable, no? What do you think?

Comment: There's no reason for having the sequence, you could just use `EN:` and `FR:` without the dashes. Also, please do not alter the question after an answer has been posted.